# Why is AJAX GET request only working once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to run a script to switch some electrical plugs on a WebApp and it works perfect but here comes the problem it only works once and I can't figure out why. 
I've also recognized that there is an XHR request going on forever without receiving a response as soon as I call the function.

Here is the function on my node JS server and on my Web App:

```
 function ajaxChangePlug(num,state) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: `/api/${num}/${state}`,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { 
                        state: state,
                        num: num
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                })
            };
```

```
        function handle1(num,state){
                ajaxChangePlug(num,state);
                if (state === "on") {
                    document.getElementById("1").setAttribute( "onClick", `handle1(${num},'off')`);
                    document.getElementById("1").src=`/resources/${num}_on.png`
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("1").setAttribute( "onClick", `handle1(${num},'on')`);
                    document.getElementById("1").src=`/resources/${num}.png`
                }    
            };
```

```
server.get('/api/:num/:state', (req, res) => {
    var state = req.params.state;
    var num = req.params.num;
    if(state === 'on'){
        shell.exec(`/home/pi/mynode/${num}${state}_on.sh`);

    }else{
        shell.exec(`/home/pi/mynode/${num}${state}_off.sh`);        
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe a cache problem, but I imagine that you first looked if you have an error message before posting, and that you considered that on our side we had to guess?

Comment: perhaps you should respond in the server side code

Comment: I also tried res.send() at the end but it didn't work and there is no error message at all it is just like the server is in a loop without an end.

Comment: How do you call `ajaxChangePlug` and what do you do when you get a response?  Specifically, are you overwriting your html and need event delegation?

Comment: So I added the the call of ajaxChangePlug as an edit above. I don't really react on a response but I change the HTML depending on the state (on/off) but I do not really see a problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for the response in you front-end like this:

```js
$.ajax({
url: `/api/${num}/${state}`,
type: "GET",
data: {
 state: state,
 num: num
},
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
 if (data.state === "on") {
  document.getElementById("1").setAttribute("onClick", `handle1(${num},'off')`);
  document.getElementById("1").src = `/resources/${num}_on.png`
 } else {
  document.getElementById("1").setAttribute("onClick", `handle1(${num},'on')`);
  document.getElementById("1").src = `/resources/${num}.png`
 }
}
})
```

In your backend you should send the response like this:

```js
server.get('/api/:num/:state', (req, res) => {
 var state = req.params.state;
 var num = req.params.num;
 if (state === 'on') {
  shell.exec(`/home/pi/mynode/${num}${state}_on.sh`);
  res.send('on');
 } else {
  shell.exec(`/home/pi/mynode/${num}${state}_off.sh`);
  res.send('off')
 }
});
```